# How can you change the appearance of a JavaFX FileChooser using CSS?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm looking to change the appearance of a FileChooser using CSS. Doing this using SceneBuilder would also be nice please, but since FileChooser does not belong to javafx.scene.controls there doesn't appear to be a straightforward way to do this. I would like to be able to set things such as font, colors, etc. I'd prefer to do this through CSS, but I don't see how to do this directly in the Java code either. Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: The [Javadocs for `FileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html) say "Provides support for standard platform file dialogs. These dialogs have look and feel of the platform UI components which is independent of JavaFX." I think this implies you cannot change the style.

Comment: `FileChooser` is a `final` class so we cant even override its methods to change the UI

Answer (score 1):

The native operating system's window manager handles the Open/Save dialog. Since FileChooser is a final class this won't be possible. You would have to implement your own custom control to customize the style.

Check this [link](https://github.com/ricemery/FileChooserFx) for a project on GitHub, FileChooserFx, that attempts to do just that. They provide a "FileChooser" from scratch approach that you could implement in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The look and feel of the File chooser is *dependent on the UI platform (OS)* and you *cannot* change this